# Need to replace names containing greater than or equals to 3 times repeated alphabets with pattern "AAA" with nothing

Tags: r

I have a some names which contains repeating characters as shown below . Need to replace names containing greater than or equals to 3 repeating alphabets with pattern "AAA" with nothing.

```
    A           
1  SaaAm
2  RoYYy
3  Pearl
4  AAA
5  AAa
6  BBbb
7  Aaria
```

Results should be as below .

```
    A
1
2
3   Pearl
4
5
6
7   Aaria
```

Comment: I have tried gsub with "([[:alpha:]])\\1+" but didn't work the way i wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you may try

```
gsub(".*(?i)(?:([[:alpha:]]))\\1{2,}.*", "", df1$A, perl=TRUE)
#[1] ""      ""      "Pearl" ""      ""      ""      "Aaria"
```